# Yii 2: multiple relation with same table

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, relation

I've got a problem with Yii 2 Relation Tables. My work has many relations, but only in this case return me an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'father.name' in 'where clause'

I think the problem is the double relation with the same Table "Agent". See the piece of code in the model:

```
public function getAgent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Agent::className(), ['id' => 'id_agent']);
}
public function getFather()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Agent::className(), ['id' => 'id_father']);
}
```

In my GridView I see the correct values, but when I try to filter with ORDER or with "andWhere", Yii2 returns the error.

Below you can find the piece of code for the searchModel:

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['agentName'] = [ 
        'asc' => ['agent.name' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['agent.name' => SORT_DESC],
        'default' => SORT_ASC
    ];

$dataProvider->sort->attributes['fatherName'] = [
        //'asc' => ['father.name' => SORT_ASC],
        //'desc' => ['father.name' => SORT_DESC],
        'default' => SORT_ASC
    ];
//.......
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'agent.name', $this->agentName]);
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'father.name', $this->fatherName]);
```

The agentName attributes works fine.
Any suggestion?
Thank you!

**-------UPDATE: more code---------**
searchModel:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $agent_aux = new Agent();
    $agent_id= $agent_aux->getAgentIdFromUser();

    if (Yii::$app->user->can('admin')){
        $query = Contract::find();
    }
    else{

        $query = Contract::find()->where(['contract.agent_id' => $agent_id]);            
    }

    $query->joinWith(['agent','seminar']);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    $this->load($params);
    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['seminar_location'] = [
        'asc' => ['seminar.location' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['seminar.location' => SORT_DESC],
    ];
    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['agentName'] = [ 
        'asc' => ['agent.name' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['agent.name' => SORT_DESC],
        'default' => SORT_ASC
    ];

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['fatherName'] = [
        //'asc' => ['father.name' => SORT_ASC],
        //'desc' => ['father.name' => SORT_DESC],
        'default' => SORT_ASC
    ];
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'data' => $this->data,
        'id_agent' => $this->id_agent,
        'id_father' => $this->id_father,
        'id_seminar' => $this->id_seminar,
    ]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'agent.name', $this->agentName]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'father.name', $this->fatherName]);
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: Might be you have misspelled column name.

Comment: @InsaneSkulll if I use "agent" as column name (now I use "father", the name of the relation) the search filters the data with the first relation (Agent) :/

Comment: Do you have a line $query->with(['agent', 'father']) or anything like that? Can you show the full source of the query?

Comment: @robsch i have "$query->joinWith(['agent']);" .... if i use "$query->joinWith(['agent','father']);" yii 2 returns the PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'agent'

Comment: Can you provide more code and show the table definiton? [Here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5137) is a similar problem. Not sure if this is the same as your problem. But have a look, please. And wouldn't the use of with(...) be appropriate? And I would assume that you have to use two joins.

Comment: @robsch ok,i've added more code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to do following changes in your model. from clause is actually creating an alias. agent and father relation will be picked in seperate join clauses. Use "agent" and "father" alias in your filter criteria with column names.

```
public function getAgent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Agent::className(), ['id' => 'id_agent'])->from(['agent' => Agent::tableName()]);
}

public function getFather()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Agent::className(), ['id' => 'id_father'])->from(['father' => Agent::tableName()])
}
```

Another thing to change is

```
$query->joinWith(['agent','seminar', 'father']);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the answer of @FidoXLNC could be to define the alias when you're doing the join:

```
$query->joinWith([
    'seminar', 
    'agent'  => function ($q) { $q->from(Agent::tableName() . ' agent' ); },
    'father' => function ($q) { $q->from(Agent::tableName() . ' father'); }
]);
```

But AFAIK you have to specify both relations, not just only one.